# OpenSSL cmd analog for ECIESwithAES-CBC encryption with BouncyCastle provider?

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, elliptic-curve

Is there a way to achieve compatible encryption result using OpenSSL command line tools to the result that I have in Java code? In Java there is an asymmetric encryption of some data with EC public key:

```
PublicKey publicKey = KeyUtils.readPublicKey(publicKeyPath, "EC");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES-CBC/NONE/PKCS7Padding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
```

But I don't know how to reproduce the same encryption in OpenSSL in command line to be able to decrypt the result in Java then.

Comment: There is no command-line tool in OpenSSL to do that.

Comment: As I understand things, there are three libraries that support ECIES. They are Botan, BouncyCastle and Crypto++. There are probley more, but those are the ones I know about. OpenSSL is not one of them.

Comment: @jww thank for you for your reply! Seems like Crypto++ is what I need. Do you know some libraries for iOS? I was originally asking about OpenSSL because I have some experience with this library. But the best solution would be to find something in Swift/ObjC to simplify things.

Comment: I think Botan would probably be the best choice because of `ECIESwithAES-CBC`. Crypto++ supports ECIES, but I believe the XOR algorithm is simply HMAC-SHA1. I believe Botan supports AES-CBC. You can find Jack Lloyd's GitHub for Botan at [randombit/botan](https://github.com/randombit/botan). Both Crypto++ and Botan support iOS.